# Node-Express error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: node.js, express

I've just started learning Node.js and i'm trying to create a web application that returns the form in users.ejs when http://localhost:8083 is entered. What is going wrong here?

**./index.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql=require("mysql");

var app = express();
 

var usersRouter=require('./routes/users');

app.use("/",usersRouter);
 
var server = app.listen(8083, function(){
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Server started at http://localhost:%s", port);
});
```

**./routes/users.js**

```
var express=require("express");
var router=express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render("./views/users");
})

module.exports = router;
```

**./views/users.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="user-detail">
    <h2>Create User Data</h2>
    <form action="/users/create" method="POST">
          <label>Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Full Name" name="fullName" required>
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="emailAddress" required>
          <label>City</label>
          <input type="city" placeholder="Enter Full City" name="city" required>
          <label>Country</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Full Country" name="country" required>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view engine for rendering the template file is not configured.

You need to setup the view engine on the app level via `app.set` method, by setting `view engine` to `ejs` :

> view engine
>
> String    The default engine extension to use when omitted. NOTE:
> Sub-apps will inherit the value of this setting.
>
> https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.settings.table

so in index.js add this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

also, you need to install `ejs`

```
npm i -S ejs
```

and include it, so your index.js file should look like this

```
var ejs = require('ejs');

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Now the view engine is set, but your users router will fail with this error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "./vies/users" in views directory
```

It's this method here:

```
res.render("./views/users");
```

It's now trying to load users template from `views/views`, i.e. there's an extra `view`. It's coming from yet another app setting - `views`, a directory to store and read view templates:

> views
>
> String or Array   A directory or an array of directories for the
> application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order
> they occur in the array
>
> Default: process.cwd() + '/views'
>
> https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.settings.table

It's configured by setting the `views` path on the app level, like so:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

And as you can see, it's already set to `process.cwd() + '/views'` by default, so it's optional, which means that's where that extra `view` is coming from, so you just need to remove `views/` in the users router, so it'll pick it up from the root by default:

```
res.render("./users");
```

Final code:

./index.js

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

// load ejs template renderer
var ejs = require("ejs");

// register the given template engine 
app.set("view engine', 'ejs");


// optional, as it defaults to process.cwd() + '/views'
// needs path too:
// var path = require("path");
//app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));


var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

app.use("/", usersRouter);

var server = app.listen(8083, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Server started at http://localhost:%s", port);
});
```

./routes/users.js

```
var express=require("express");
var router=express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render("./users");
})

module.exports = router;
```

Check Express guide and examples here:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/examples.html